# how to expand @137b866 in soap ui using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

in soap ui we usually get values like 
"com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep@137b866"

what does it mean and how can we expand it?

Answer (score 0):

That means you have an instance of [WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.html)

So you should be able to just call the methods in the documentation I linked to, ie:

```
obj.description
```

(which will call `getDescription()`)

Comment: thanks tim_yates, I have used obj.description and getDescription() but it is not displaying anything. Do you have any idea that how can we get list of existing methods for this instance.

Comment: They are all in the documentation link, no?

Comment: thanks tim_yates, but there is no documentaion for that.

Comment: No documentation for what?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have an object which is an instance of this class, and probably you're invoking `toString()` method on this object, by default if you don't override `toString()` method on specific object you get `objectClassName@hashcodenumber`.

If you want to see the WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep methods you can take a look on the [API](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.html). However if you want to see dynamically a list of all methods for an specific object with groovy, you can do it in a java way using reflection. For example if you have an object instance of some class you can get the class `obj.getClass()`an invoking  [`obj.getClass().getMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) or [`obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) in this object you get a list of all of its methods. See the example below:

```
def obj = 'sample test'

// Returns an array of Method objects reflecting all the methods declared by the class 
// or interface represented by this Class object. (from java API)
def declaredMethods = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()
// Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the public member methods 
// of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including those declared 
// by the class or interface and those inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces.
def methods = obj.getClass().getMethods()

log.info "DECLARED METHODS"

// print the method names
for(declaredMethod in declaredMethods){
    log.info declaredMethod
}

log.info "METHODS"

// print more method names
for(method in methods){
    log.info method
}

// i.e invoke indexOf(int) using reflection
def classArray = new Class[1]
classArray[0] = String.class
def indexOfMethod = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("indexOf", classArray)
def result = indexOfMethod.invoke(obj,'test')
log.info "using reflection: 'sample test'.indexOf('test') =" + result
log.info "normal invocation: 'sample test'.indexOf('test') =" + obj.indexOf('test')
```

(I use log.info in the sample because I executed in soapui groovy testStep)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hope this was helpful :)